# ARM S3C6410 kernel boot

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

I am working on ARM S3C6410 device now.
The problem is first 256KB of NAND was broken.
I am trying to boot with SD card, uboot works.
What I want to know is as following.

1. Can I boot kernel from SD card without NAND?
2. Can I run uboot from SD card, and then boot kernel from non-broken area of NAND?

I am a newbie. I hope guru's help.

Comment: This isn't a programming question - it is a platform usage question.
I'm sure it's possible, as long as your u-boot has NAND drivers, but it is a bit off topic. Please come back with any issues you come across while trying to implement any lacking software support.

Comment: @unixsmurt, Could you let me know where can I post this question?

Comment: Maybe try electronics.stackexchange.com when your questions are not directly related to programming, but more on hardware.

Comment: @ttotto: Did you ever solve this?  What was your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, many boards use sd-card instead of nand, just modify the `bootargs` in u-boot. You probably don't even need to change the kernel, just make sure that uboot supports the SD-card for your platform as a boot device
2. yes. Again, it's only a problem of configuring `bootargs` correctly. Probably even simpler than point 1